# How to fix PivotItem causing "Value does not fall within expected range" error?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, pivot

I'm trying to create a `Pivot` control with 2 `PivotItem`s, as follows:

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:Pivot HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Title="" Width="300" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">

            <!--Pivot item one-->
            <phone:PivotItem >
                <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="item1" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Arial" Margin="0,30,0,0"/>
                </phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <Grid/>
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <!--Pivot item two-->
            <phone:PivotItem >
                <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="item2" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Arial" Margin="0,30,0,0"/>
                </phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <Grid/>
            </phone:PivotItem>              
        </phone:Pivot>
    </Grid>
```

The first `PivotItem` is fine, but the second one is giving me the error "Value does not fall within expected range", e.g.:

[image]

What is the correct way to add multiple pivot items to a Pivot control?

Comment: `<phone:PivotItem.Header>`*is* a header on the pivot item

Comment: I have pasted your snippet which shows the same error like the screenshot. But clean and rebuild the application works fine. Can you please try rebuid the application

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've added an answer stating what you said. Simply building the application fixes it.

Comment: You want me to upvote your comment?

Comment: ya, because next time someone see the Q/A and comments can helps to understand easly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a non-issue. That error disappears when I build the application.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue actually. Press F7, it will be hide automatically.